# Axiomatizations of the real exponential field

Tags: reference-request, model-theory

According to Marker's ["Model Theory: An Introduction"](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b98860/page/1), the real exponential field has a $\forall\exists$ axiomatization (because it is model complete) but no-one has any idea what such an axiomatization might look like. Has any progress been made on this since  the early 2000s when Marker wrote this?

Answer (score 7):

In her PhD thesis ``[On the First Order Theory of Real Exponentiation](http://www.oocities.org/tamara_servi/servithesis.pdf)'', Tamara Servi, has given a recursive subtheory
$T$ of $T_{exp}$ and has shown that if Schanuel's conjecture holds, then $T$ is complete and hence provides a recursive axiomatization of $T_{exp}$. There are some related results.

See section 4.7 of the above mentioned paper.